# MS SQL SP saves call of other SP into temp table, can it be avoided?

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures, common-table-expression

we have a stored procedure (A) that calls another stored procedure (B) and saves the result into a temp table.

The second stored procedure (B) contains 2 while loops and ordering, and it's giving us performance issues at a client's.

The reason we have that 2nd SP (B) is because it is used by other SP's, so if we need to change anything we can do so at that one place only.

I have modified the 2nd SP (B) to remove the loops and used a recursive CTE, however, the 1st SP (A) still calls it and saves its result into a temp table.

Would it be possible to avoid saving the result into a temp table and somehow simply use the resultset returned by the 2nd SP (B)?

Comment: Maybe. Maybe not. No one here has access to your code, nor your full requirements. Why not try it in your test environment & see how it works?

Comment: Depends on what you do with the SP(A) results after you save them in the temp table.

Comment: Refactor B as a table valued function?

Comment: What are you doing with the result of SP B inside of SP A?

Comment: SP A calls SP B and saves the result in a temp table to then remove duplicates, inner join with a real table to get only matching records and finally big select with a few joins to get the actual text values of items since SP B only returns IDs.